# Rewrite Rules - Differentiate between Angular #! and Angular without #!

Tags: angularjs, regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

How do I write Rewrite Rules in IIS to handle these scenarios:

Folder Structure:

```
[AngularApp1]
  -- app.js
  -- appController.js
  -- index.html
[AngularSecondApp]
  -- app.js
  -- appController.js
  -- index.html
[DomainSubApp]
  -- app.js
  -- appController.js
  -- index.html
favicon.ico
gulpfile.js
web.config
```

`AngularApp1` is **NOT** *HTML5* configured, and is using the **DEFAULT** `#!` prefix.  So pages typically look like: `https://(www.)?mywebsite.com/#!/state...`

`AngularSecondApp` **IS** configured in *HTML5* mode, and uses **NO** `''` hashPrefix.  So pages typically look like: `https://(www.)?mywebsite.com/state...`

`DomainSubApp` is **NOT** *HTML5* configured, and is using the **DEFAULT** `#!` prefix.  Pages typically look like: `https://domainsubapp.mywebsite.com/#!/state...`

## Routing

> The server should be using `AngularSecondApp/index.html` if:
>
> - the subdomain is `''` or `'www'` AND...
> - The URI? is: `^/\w+/?.*$` -- But not Files

...

> The server should be using `DomainSubApp/index.html` if:
>
> - the subdomain is `DomainSubApp`

...

> **Otherwise**, the server should be using `AngularApp1/index.html` INCLUDING:
>
> - the subdomain is `''` or `'www'` AND...
> - The URI? is: `^/(#!/.*)?$` -- But not Files

## My Personal Confusion

I realize you need to take FILES into consideration.  For example, `http://mywebsite.com/favicon.ico` or `http://mywebsite.com/someFile.ext` or `http://mywebsite.com/scripts/scriptFile.js`.  So some of my attempts failed because my Patterns were too generic.  Therefore, requests for files were ALSO rewritten/redirected.

Do I need to do anything to ensure the Angular Routing Persists?  So, if I go to `http://mywebsite.com/route/param1/param2`, that should be rewritten/redirected to `http://mywebsite.com/AngularSecondApp/index.html`  Where does `route/param1/param2` go?

## What I **HAD**:

I say "Had" because I previously required a Sub-Folder in the URL named `AngularSecondApp`, such as: `https://(www.)?mywebsite.com/AngularSecondApp/state...`.  This made things easier.  But the brass wants me to get rid of that subfolder in the URL, hence this trouble.

So this is what I had:

```
    <clear />
    /*https forced redirect is here... irrelevant*/

    <rule name="AngularSecondApp rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^AngularSecondApp/.*$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularSecondApp/index.html" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="AngularApp1 redirect">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(/AngularApp1)?/index\.html$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="AngularApp1 rewrite">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularApp1/index.html" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Don't confuse *redirect* with *rewrite*. The URL `http://mywebsite.com/route/param1/param2` should be *rewritten* to the proper  SPA `index.htm` file.

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you, that tiny comment actually does clear up a side-question I had and helps me understand the flow.  So if somebody DOES directly try to hit one of those `index.html` "SPA" files, then that does an actual *redirect* to the *Route* I want.  Then a *rewrite* occurs which *rewrites* the *Route* to utilize the correct "SPA" `index.html`.  Redirect turns a direct Path URL into a Route.  Then Rewrite turns a Route into a Path URL, but only behind the scenes (So it isn't an infinite loop).

Answer (score 0):

As an artifact of a day long past, the Rewrites I "HAD" included a Redirect in case people directly visited an `index.html` page.  Also, I was under the impression that any Rewrite you took action to (So rewriting `/` to `index.html`) had to have a Redirect.  That was incorrect.

Therefore, after GeorgeAWG's comment, I ended up ditching the Redirects and only doing Rewrites.  This simplified my life, and could possibly simply everybody's life.

```
    <rule name="AngularSecondApp rewrite">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(/\w+)+/?$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularSecondApp/index.html" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="AngularApp1 rewrite">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularApp1/index.html" />
    </rule>
```

So if the Request URI begins with word characters, it will rewrite to the second app.

I'm not sure how the AngularApp1 is working... because it works for root `/`, but it also works for `/#!/route...`  But it doesn't throw off files like `/scripts/lol.js`.  So my answer solves the problem, but is missing some understanding.